# Drag and Drop - Multiple items

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

Im trying to develop a simple cocoa application in objective-C, everything is going well but I have a concern regarding the next issue.

I need to drag and drop 3 different items (which different meanings) into a day schedule.

Something like this

```
[o Item] [x Item] [z Item] 

00:00|--|--|--|--|--|--|--| 23:59
```

Im playing a little with dragImage feature and Im able to move the items (which are images btw).

- Which is the best way to achieve my goal in tearms of good design?
- Do I need to define 3 different views for each item and one destination area for all of them?(the schedule in this case)
- How do I handle the time related to a drop in the schedule? I think using the pixel location within the view and calculating it but I dont know if there is a better way.

I have read the Apple documentation and different topics related to drag and drop, I understand it but I dont know the most professional way to achieve my goal.

Comment: On Mac OS X v10.6 and later, a pasteboard can contain multiple items.

Comment: Having multiple items in my pasteboard is not "the problem". I dont mean to do that, I can define 3 different pasteboards. My question goes about which general steeps should I follow. So far I have a 3 different views which hold the items to be drag, I can drag them into another view (a representation of the hours of a day) and now I guess I should take the image from the pasteboard and draw it where the drop was done. But how I handle then for modifying the elements already placed? Im a little bit lost in terms of design patterns for this..